# Read for each button send name from sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
con.Open();
foreach (Control c in MainDownPanel.Controls)
{
    if (c is Button)
    {      
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from inventorymaster ", con);
        SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (read.Read())
        {
            c.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
        }
        read.Close();
    }
}
con.Close();
```

The problem is that in all my buttons I get the last SQL value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name from inventorymaster ", con);
SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
foreach (Control c in MainDownPanel.Controls)
{
        if (c is Button && read.Read())
        {
                c.Text = (read["name"].ToString());
        }
}

 read.Close();
 con.Close();
```